# Full iteration over a list from a specific index in python

Tags: python, list, iteration

How can I iterate over a list beginning from a specific index.

for example:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I want to start iterating from `list(3)` which is `"d"`, but I want the iteration to continue over all elements. So it will iterate in this order `"d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't name your variable `list`. It'll clash with the builtin `list` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list slicing to build a *new* list object:

```
for elem in lst[3:] + lst[:3]:
```

This is fine for small lists; creating the new list objects (for the slicing and the concatenation result) is cheap enough.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
>>> for elem in lst[3:] + lst[:3]:
...     print elem, 
... 
d e f a b c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to make a cyclic iterator out of the list. 
Then slice `len(seq)` elements from the iterator, starting from index 3.

```
In [573]: seq = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

In [574]: import itertools as IT

In [575]: list(IT.islice(IT.cycle(seq), 3, 3+len(seq)))
Out[575]: ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This also works but since the lists I will use this code for are relatively small I choose Martijn's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, (although I'd probably go for Martijn's / unutbu's approaches):

```
from collections import deque

lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

d = deque(lst)
d.rotate(-3)
for el in d:
    # do something
```

If you needed to keep *rotating* the data and iterate over it from the start or reverse from the end, then this will be more efficient. However, it does mean you lose access to being able to directly index into `d` - since it's effectively a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Deques are not an option. The code I am working on iterates over the list until a condition is met. During the iteration I sometimes remove elements from the list. With deque's you can't do this.

Comment: @krypt to be fair - that's not exactly obvious from your question... iterating over a list and removing elements also sounds like a recipe for disaster...

Comment: Yeah it was not a part of the question. I just wanted to tell why deque's aren't an option. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with modulus(%) operator without using any package:

```
>>> for i in range(3,3+len(lst)):
...    print lst[i%len(lst)],
... 
d e f a b c
```